# Cantering Headings in \multicolumn automatically with Sub-headings without overflowing lines?

Tags: tables, formatting, multirow, multicolumn

## Set up

Using the MWE below I'm trying to centre "Heading 1" with the 4 subheadings, and "Headings 2" and "Heading 3" with their subheadings respectively:

## MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}

%MARGIN SETTINGS
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{
    paper=a4paper, 
    inner=2.5cm, 
    outer=2.5cm, 
    bindingoffset=0.0cm, 
    top=2.5cm, 
    bottom=2.5cm,
    headsep=4.5mm, 
    footskip=7.4mm, 
    %showframe
    }

%FOR TABLES
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 1pt}}


%----------------------BEGIN-------------------------

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
  \begin{tabular}{l|l ? S|S|S|S  ? S|S ? S|S} %S centres
  %\begin{tabular}{l|l ? S|S|S|S  | S|S | S|S}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{Column 1} & 
    \multirow{2}{*}{Column 2} &  %& &
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{Heading 1} & %& 
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{Heading 2} & 
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{Heading 3} \\
       & & {Sub 1} & {Sub 2} & {Sub 3} & {Sub 4} & {Sub 1} & {Sub 2} & {Sub 1} & {Sub 2} \\
          \midrule
    A1 = item1 & 0.0001  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
    %\hline
    A2 = item2 & 0.0002 & 1 & 1 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
    %\hline
    A3 = item3 & 0.0003  & 1 & 1 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}}
    \caption{Test Table} \label{tbl:BPF}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

## The Problem

If i use more `&`'s to align the headings i get the following error. The vertical lines have overflowed to the top:

[image]

## Goal

How to centre the headings (as above) but without the overflowing vertical lines in between "Sub 1 Sub 2" and "Sub 4 Sub 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, what you want. Do you mean like this? If so: you have to specify the correct number of columns in `\multicolumn` (4 in case of "Heading 1"). To have the vertical rules, just add those to the column type specification of `\multicolumn`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}

%MARGIN SETTINGS
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{
    paper=a4paper, 
    inner=2.5cm, 
    outer=2.5cm, 
    bindingoffset=0.0cm, 
    top=2.5cm, 
    bottom=2.5cm,
    headsep=4.5mm, 
    footskip=7.4mm, 
    %showframe
    }

%FOR TABLES
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 1pt}}


%----------------------BEGIN-------------------------

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
  \begin{tabular}{l|l ? S|S|S|S  ? S|S ? S|S} %S centres
  %\begin{tabular}{l|l ? S|S|S|S  | S|S | S|S}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{Column 1} & 
    \multirow{2}{*}{Column 2} &  %& &
      \multicolumn{4}{c?}{Heading 1} & %& 
      \multicolumn{2}{c?}{Heading 2} & 
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{Heading 3} \\
       & & {Sub 1} & {Sub 2} & {Sub 3} & {Sub 4} & {Sub 1} & {Sub 2} & {Sub 1} & {Sub 2} \\
          \midrule
    A1 = item1 & 0.0001  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
    %\hline
    A2 = item2 & 0.0002 & 1 & 1 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
    %\hline
    A3 = item3 & 0.0003  & 1 & 1 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}}
    \caption{Test Table} \label{tbl:BPF}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In general it is considered as bad practice to resize a table. Instead you could use `\small` to make it fit in the text width. Also, tables tend to look better with less (read 'no') vertical lines. You might consider to use the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}

%MARGIN SETTINGS
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{
    paper=a4paper, 
    inner=2.5cm, 
    outer=2.5cm, 
    bindingoffset=0.0cm, 
    top=2.5cm, 
    bottom=2.5cm,
    headsep=4.5mm, 
    footskip=7.4mm, 
    %showframe
    }

%FOR TABLES
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}


%----------------------BEGIN-------------------------

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[H]
  \small
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{ll  SSSS   SS  SS} %S centres
  %\begin{tabular}{l|l ? S|S|S|S  | S|S | S|S}
    \toprule
     & &
      \multicolumn{4}{c}{Heading 1} & %& 
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{Heading 2} & 
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{Heading 3} \\
      \cmidrule(rl){3-6}
      \cmidrule(rl){7-8}
      \cmidrule(rl){9-10}
     Column 1& Column 2& {Sub 1} & {Sub 2} & {Sub 3} & {Sub 4} & {Sub 1} & {Sub 2} & {Sub 1} & {Sub 2} \\
          \midrule
    A1 = item1 & 0.0001  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
    %\hline
    A2 = item2 & 0.0002 & 1 & 1 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
    %\hline
    A3 = item3 & 0.0003  & 1 & 1 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
    \caption{Test Table} \label{tbl:BPF}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! Exactly like that. Is there also an option to have the bold lines in-between "Sub 4 Sub 1" and "Sub 2 Sub 1"  to overflow to the top? As it is in the original image? (i.e the same hight as is in-between "column2 Sub1").